# Error - Cannot access display string yet for new node creation in Omnet

Tags: c++, c++11, omnet++, inet

I am trying to create a node at run time in my module in Omnet. I am able to create it with this code and its working fine.

```
cModule* parentmod = getParentModule();
cModule* grantParentMod = parentmod->getParentModule();
cModule* grantParentMod1 = grantParentMod->getParentModule();
// To check if the module is already created
for (cSubModIterator iter(*grantParentMod1); !iter.end(); iter++)
{
    EV << iter()->getFullName()<<endl;
    if (iter()->getFullName() == "host_send4")
        return;
 }
cModuleType *meshnode1 = cModuleType::get("inet.networklayer.manetrouting.PASER.meshnode");
cModule *mod = meshnode1->create("host_send4", grantParentMod1);
cDisplayString& dispstr =  getDisplayString();
dispstr.parse("p=1000,535;r=200,green");
mod->finalizeParameters();
mod->buildInside();
mod->scheduleStart(simTime()+2*beaconInterval);
```

However this module is not generated at desired place in simulation output (the coordinates and the display). I believe the display string created here is not attached to the module and hence I tried to do it by this :-

```
cDisplayString& dispstr =  getDisplayString();
dispstr.parse("p=1000,535;r=200,green");
mod->getDisplayString().set(dispstr);
```

But with this I encounter following error at run time :- **Cannot access display string yet: Parameters not yet set up** . I know the problem is in `mod->getDisplayString().set(dispstr);` 
So is there any other way to assign the parameter or am I doing some minor error. 
Thanks for this help.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are following the module creation procedure as given in the OMNeT++ [manual](http://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec186).

If you navigate to the **The Detailed Procedure** sub-section you will notice a comprehensive list which tells what step should be performed where:

> 1. Find the factory object;
> 2. Create the module;
> 3. Set up its parameters and gate sizes as needed;
> 4. Tell the (possibly compound) module to recursively create its internal submodules and connections;
> 5. Schedule activation message(s) for the new simple module(s).

Step `3` I believe is the one you are looking for. Little below is given a detailed explanation of what should be done for step `3`:

> If you want to set up parameter values or gate vector sizes (Step
>   3.), the code goes between the `create()` and `buildInside()` calls:
>
> ```
> // create
> cModuleType *moduleType = cModuleType::get("foo.nodes.WirelessNode");
> cModule *module = moduleType->create("node", this);
>
> // set up parameters and gate sizes before we set up its submodules
> module->par("address") = ++lastAddress;
> module->finalizeParameters();
>
> module->setGateSize("in", 3);
> module->setGateSize("out", 3);
>
> // create internals, and schedule it
> module->buildInside();
> module->scheduleStart(simTime());
> ```

Be aware of the usage of the `module->par("<parameter_name>")` function.

PS: I was writing my answer, and in meanwhile you answered your own question. This answer can be left there for future reference, if useful.

Answer (score 1):

Well I modified the code as :-

```
cModuleType *meshnode1 = cModuleType::get("inet.networklayer.manetrouting.PASER.meshnode");
    cModule *mod = meshnode1->create("host_send4", grantParentMod1);
    mod->finalizeParameters();

    std::string displayString = "p=1000,535;r=200,green;i=device/smallrouter";
    mod->getDisplayString().parse(displayString.c_str());

    mod->buildInside();
    mod->scheduleStart(simTime()+2*beaconInterval);
```

and then its working perfect. According to my understanding, I should add `mod->finalizeParameters();` before changing the display setting and display string should be a simple string but not the cDisplayString object.